# Error: Could not find or load main class shoutbox.ShoutBox

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, compiler-errors

I'm very new to Java, and to programming in general. I'm working on the following code using the NetBeans IDE:

```
package ShoutBox;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ShoutBox {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    ShoutBox shoutbox = new ShoutBox();
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = 0;


    public void message() {

        String message[] = new String[10]; // declare array

        message[0] = "01: Free Will Exists.";
        message[1] = "02: Since Free Will Exists, Evil Exists.";
        message[2] = "03: Evil, being evil, will not stop on its own.";
        message[3] = "04: For Good to continue to exist, Evil must be stopped.";
        message[4] = "05: It is good that Good exists.";
        message[5] = "06: It is good to stop evil.";
        message[6] = "07: Good persons will attempt to stop evil or else they are not good.";
        message[7] = "08: Evil brings war.";
        message[8] = "09: Since evil brings war and will not stop, good must fight and win those wars.";
        message[9] = "10: Just war exists.";

        System.out.println();

        String cm = new ShoutBox().shoutOutCannedMessage(message); //call to shoutOutCannedMessage
        String rm = new ShoutBox().shoutOutRandomMessage(message);
        System.out.println("Philosophy: ");
        System.out.println(cm);
        System.out.println("Your Random Message: ");
        System.out.println(rm);


    }

    public String shoutOutCannedMessage(String[] message)
    { 
    ShoutBox shoutbox = new ShoutBox();
        for (String element : message)
        {
            System.out.println(element); //print out messages
        }

        System.out.print("Select a message: ");
        System.out.println();

        selection = input.nextInt();

        String cannedMessage = message[selection];

        return cannedMessage;


    }


}
```

It builds and loads just fine, but won't run and gives me the error code: "Error: Could not find or load main class shoutbox.ShoutBox." Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Did you accidently put a close bracket `}` after `ShoutBox box = new ShoutBox();` ?

Comment: I'll try removing one.

Comment: That just created more errors down the line. I'm not sure where the closing } should go if not there.

Comment: Is your `Scanner input` line supposed to go inside the main method? Right now it's not in any method.

Comment: I placed the Scanner input inside the main method like this:public class shoutbox {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    shoutbox shoutbox = new shoutbox();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = 0;
    }
but am now getting a message that "variable shoutbox is not used". The same goes for "input" and "selection."

Comment: Well, you're setting the variables but not doing anything with them. Remember that the program starts by calling the main method, so those four lines are going to execute, but if you want to execute your other methods you're going to have to call them from the main method.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't run is because packages in java (and class names) are case-sensitive. You should declare package as `package shoutbox` instead.

By naming conventions, you should always name your packages in lowercase (your folders that denote packages should be done likewise), and you would always capitalize your class names.

Comment: I renamed it without caps, but now I'm getting this error message: 

error: cannot find symbol
        String rm = new shoutbox().shoutOutRandomMessage(message);
  symbol:   method shoutOutRandomMessage(String[])
  location: class shoutbox

Comment: I meant to rename the package, not the actual name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a completely new file and placed the Main method in that, and separated the rest of the code into three files. It ran just fine after that.